# Turn a DataFrame into Panel Data Structure

Tags: python, pandas, panel, reshape

I am trying to reshape a Pandas DataFrame into a Panel Structure. I have the reshaped data that I ultimately want to use from Stata, but I want to do the reshaping in Python. Here is a link to the original data: http://www.wiod.org/protected3/data13/SEA/WIOD_SEA_July14.xlsx

And the reshaped data: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1_onjqzvT3LJnYOEuUhRC1RDS3iH7TupK

I used the following code, but it does not seem to work:

```
import pandas as pd

p=pd.read_excel('WIOD_SEA_July14.xlsx', sheetname='DATA')

pd.melt(p,id_vars=['Variable','Country','Code'],value_vars=['_1995','_1996','_1997','_1998','_1999','_2000','_2001','_2002','_2003','_2004','_2005','_2006','_2007','_2008','_2009','_2010','_2011'])
```

p.T

Can anyone help me with the reshaping? Python does not understand that the data has a panel structure. I have to reshape it to be in a panel format.

Comment: It may not be right but `df.pivot()` may work. Problem I see there is potential for duplicate indices.

Comment: Just FYI, [`Panel` is deprecated and will be removed in a future version.](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20.3/whatsnew.html#deprecate-panel)